# Why does my recursive function with if-elif statements return None?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around learning Python and I've come to a bit of a stall on recursive functions. In [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/), one of the exercises is to write a function that determines if number *a* is a power of number *b* using the following definition:

> "A number, a, is a power of b if it is divisible by b and a/b is a power of b. Write a function called is_power that takes parameters a and b and returns True if a is a power of b."

The current state of my function is:

```
def isPower(a,b):
    return a % b == 0 and (a/b) % b == 0

print isPower(num1,num2)
```

As it is, this produces the result I expect. However the chapter is focused on writing recursive functions to reduce redundancy and I'm not quite sure how I can turn the final "(a/b) % b == 0" into a recursion. I've attempted:

```
def isPower(a,b):
    if a % b != 0:
        return False
    elif isPower((a/b),b):
        return True
```

But that just returns None.

What is the proper way to recurse this function?

Comment: you should beware that the meaning of the '/' operator has changed in Python 3+, from returning an integer to returning a float, so your code will break.  Change it to '//' instead, which will always return an int.

Comment: note that your first attempt doesn't check if a is a power of b, it cheks if a is a multiple of b^2.  try isPower(12,2), it would return True.

Comment: Just so it's said, your first version of isPower is broken -- it will only show whether `a` is a multiple of `b^2`.  It'll return true for `isPower(2, 1)`, for example, which should never be true.  For that matter, you may want to make sure any recursive version checks whether `(b==1 && a!=1)` before it continues, or it will either get stuck in an infinite loop or return the wrong thing.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `elif`, what are you expecting it to mean? Did you consider the possibility that *this* condition isn't met *either*? What do you expect to happen in this case? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting a base case, when a == 1:

```
def isPower(a,b):
    if a == 1:
        return True
    if a % b != 0:
        return False
    elif isPower((a/b),b):
        return True
    else
        return False
```

However this has some other problems - if a is 0 then it will never finish and if b is 0 then you will get a divide-by-zero.

Here is a verbose solution that as far as I can tell will work for all integer combinations:

```
def isPower(a,b):
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return False
    def realIsPower(a, b):
        if a == 1:
            return True
        elif a%b != 0:
            return False
        elif realIsPower((a/b), b):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return realIsPower(a, b)
```

EDIT: My code didn't work for cases when both a and b are negative.  I'm now comparing their absolute values.

EDIT2: Silly me, x^0 == 1, so a == 1 should ALWAYS return true.  That also means I don't have to compare a to b before the recursion.  Thanks @Javier.

Comment: Thank you. This clarified exactly what I was missing. After tinkering around some more with it earlier I had reached a maximum recursion loop, but couldn't figure out how to stop it. I guess I assumed the interpreter would know I just wanted it to stop after performing itself once more. Now I understand that, when writing a recursive call, one of the tests to even allow that ELIF branch to be reached has to be able to stop it. This was just a practice function so allowing for a base of 1 would've been fine, but thanks for going all out to help!

Comment: Hey, glad I could help!  Always remember that there are two things required for all recursive functions - a base case(s) and a recursive call.  Sometimes (such as in this case) there is more than one base case.

Answer (score 2):

you need an additional case, for when both conditionals return false

```
def isPower(a,b):
    if a % b != 0:
        return False
    elif isPower((a/b),b):
        return True
    else
        return False
```

Comment: I think you meant a % b, not a & b

Comment: This will always return false.

Comment: You need to account for the base case too, actually. I just edited away the typo.

Comment: this still does not work for me, at some point the function should return True in a non-recursive condition.

Comment: Yeah, after returning home and testing this out a bit it's consistently returning False. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: I'd shorten that to `return bool(a % b) or isPower((a//b), b) or False`. In general the `if isTrue: return True; if isFalse: return False`-type construction is ugly

Answer (score 1):

```
def isPower (a,b):
    return a==1 or (a!=0 and b!=0 and b!=1 and isPower((a/b),b))
```

Comment: This will always return true in the event that a is initially 1, however that's only the case if b is 1 or -1.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Javier. Your and Niki's answers combined were exactly what I needed for everything to click in my head. I understand the importance of scaffolding and writing overly verbose code with plenty of tests along the way, but once I'm comfortable with the syntax and logic I would like to be able to produce the shortest code possible that produces the same effect. This answer was great to see what Niki's answer looks like as a one-liner for future reference. Too bad I can't have two accepted answers!

Comment: @Niki Yoshiuchi: 1 is a power of any number  ( x^0 = 1 for any x )

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code. From what I tested, it works:

```
def ispower(a, b):

    if b == 1 or b == 0:
        return False
    if b <= 0 or a <= 0:
        return False
    if a % b == 0:
        if ((a / b) / b) == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return ispower(a / b, b)
    else:
        return False
        print ispower(-10, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
def ispower(a,b):
  if b==a:
    return True
  elif a<b:
    return False
  else:
    return ispower(a*1.0/b, b)
```

Comment: an explanation would help this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_power (a, b):

    if a == 1:
        return True
    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        return True
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return False
    if a%b != 0:
        return False
    elif is_power ((a/b), b):
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, it's a little bit cleaner:

```
def is_power(a, b):
    if a == 1:
        return True
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return False
    if a % b == 0 and is_power(a/b, b):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```