# Recursive pattern returning NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have a simple piece of code to recursively print a pattern in Python, however, when printed, the code is returning NoneType.

Here's what I have.

```
def pattern(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ''
    print ( '*' + str(pattern(n-1)) + '!', end='')
```

My expected output is

`**!!`

However, this code does work with a return statement instead of print. The problem is that I don't need the quotes.

Comment: where is the recursion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my recursive function return None?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719853/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'll *return* the value that you want to return and then print it outside your function.  e.g.:

```
def pattern(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ''
    return '*' + str(pattern(n-1)) + '!'

print(pattern(2))
```

Comment: So it's not possible to get the expected results printing inside the function? I'm curious as to why using a print statement makes the recursion return NoneType.

Comment: @23k -- Because the function has no `return` statement along that path.  If python doesn't see a `return` statement, it returns `None` by default.  You _could_ `print` _and_ `return` if you really wanted to . . .